# Download gmail into mac mail, clear gmail

Tags: gmail, apple-mail

I want to have all past gmail emails completely downloaded in Mail on mac (Current Version, Mac High Sierra) and then cleared from the gmail server. Gmail is currently FULL , so it needs to be cleared to continue receiving mail, however all the mail needs to be kept and preferably in Mail. Mail is already linked to gmail. However even though there's 15GB from gmail, if I "export" the inbox (in Mail) it only took up 150mb in the folder I exported it to.

Comment: In regards to why your Mac Mail only have of your mail - it could be set up to only download the latest 30 day or 1 year? I'm not too familiar with mac mail default, but for example Outlook for Mac has a default of only syncing the last 1 year of mail locally, and the rest - left on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout?pli=1) to export all your mails out and you will get a single file (.mbox) which then you can import the .mbox format into your Mac Mail.